# How to find basis for a subspace?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

So i have the following subspace

r − s − 2t − u

−r + 2s + 5t + 2u

s + 3t + u

3r + s + 5u

$$\begin{bmatrix}1 & -1 & -2 & -1 \\ 
-1 & 2 & 5 & 2 \\ 
0 & 1 & 3 & 1 \\ 
3 & 1 & 0 & 5 \\ 
\end{bmatrix}$$
These four equations are all put into square brackets. There are no zero's in the questions equal to the equations. This is a past exam question .

And i need to find the basis. I know that r,s,t,u are all scalars. I was thinking of decomposing these equations into variables and numbers, but i am not sure.

How would i find the basis ? Could somebody help me ? I was thinkig it might have something to do with the span.

YES i already asked the question. Please to not mark it as a duplicate.. I asked it again so more people can see it and maybe help me.

Comment: Yes. People won't answer my question . So why not ask it again

Comment: You must get the matrix to Reduced Echelon Form using permissible matrix row operations

Comment: and then how do i proceed?

Comment: Once the matrix is in reduced for the basis will consist of all linearly independent vectors.

Comment: That will be your answer.

Comment: $$\begin{bmatrix}1 & -1 & -2 & -1 \\ 
-1 & 2 & 5 & 2 \\ 
0 & 1 & 3 & 1 \\ 
3 & 1 & 0 & 5 \\ 
\end{bmatrix}\Rightarrow \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 & \frac{2}{3} \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 3 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & -\frac{2}{3} \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{bmatrix}$$
So your basis will be the vectors $(1,0,0,\frac{2}{3}), (0,1,0,3), (0,0,1, -\frac{2}{3})$